# For a wf $\mathscr{B}$, $\mathscr{B} \vdash_K (\forall x_i) \mathscr{B}$ but not always $\vdash_K \mathscr{B} \Rightarrow (\forall x_i) \mathscr{B}$.

Tags: logic

Here K is an arbitrary predicate calculus. This is the reason given in Mendelson's logic as why the deduction theorem used for propositional calculus must be modified to use in first order theory. There is an example given describing this exact scenario in question however I am unable to grasp the concept of that example.

Comment: Could you provide the example in the question? It is hard to answer without more information.

Comment: Example, consider the domain containing at least two elements c and d. Let K be any predicate calculus and let $\mathscr{B}$ be the wf $A_1^1(x_1)$. Interpret $A_1^1$ as a property that holds only for c. Then $A_1^1(x_1)$ is satisfied by any sequence $s=(s_1,s_2,…,)$ in which $s_1=c$ but $(\forall x_1) A_1^1(x)$ is satisfied by no sequence.

Answer (score 1):

In Mendelson's proof system we have That: $(x=0) \vdash_{\mathsf PA} \forall x (x=0)$, using Gen rule (where $\mathsf {PA}$ id first-order arithmetic).

But the formula $(x=0) \to \forall x (x=0)$ is not true in $\mathbb N$ and thus we want that $\nvdash_{\mathsf {PA}} (x=0) \to \forall x (x=0)$.

This is the reason for the restriction regarding the Deduction Theorem for FOL.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.